# Looking for a Code Solution to import a .mdb table to another .mdb table

Tags: c++, sql, ms-access, mfc

I am trying to update an existing database to a newer version of our .mdb database. I wanted to add a table from the newer version of our .mdb in to the existing .mdb. I was attempting to follow the following Microsoft Support Link.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200427

My setup is this:

```
   CDatabase db;
   CString SQL;

   SQL = "SELECT * INTO "
         "[ODBC;Driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=C:\\Database\\info.mdb;PWD=password;]."
         "[Diagnosis] "
         "FROM [Diagnosis]";
   try
   {
      // Open database and execute SQL statement to copy data.
      db.OpenEx( "Driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);"
                 "DBQ=C:\\Database\\newDBTemp\\info.mdb;PWD=password;",  CDatabase::noOdbcDialog );
      db.ExecuteSQL( SQL );
   }
   catch( CDBException* pEX )
   {
      // Display errors.
      AfxMessageBox( pEX->m_strError );
      pEX->Delete();
   }
```

When I run the code I get an error `You cannot use ODBC to import from, export to, or link and external Microsoft Jet or ISAM database table to your database.`

So, my question is, is there a way to copy an entire table from one database to another other than manually inputting all of the fields in? I changed the paths and variable names to make the example more concise.

Comment: What are the specific versions of MS Access?  Source and Destination.

Comment: Access 2003. It's an old program.

Comment: Deleted my suggestion to export/import using .csv since you are looking for a code solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error was related to ODBC, maybe it's better to use DAO as mentioned in [the link you provided](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200427).  Hopefully, you will find what you need given that Access 2003 is no longer supported ([Microsoft ended support for Office 2003 on April 8, 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/825796)).

> Microsoft Office Access 2003 | Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library

Reference to the Data Access Object (DAO) 3.6 library on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa163992%28office.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I'll look in to this suggestion. I also was unaware that support ended for 2003 but we have clients that have had devices for 15 years so they'd need more than software upgrades if we upgraded our devices too much.

Comment: In my experience, it took some effort to go from Access 2003 to Access 2007.  The subsequent updates were easy (2007 to 2010 to 2013).  Best of luck.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203849%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening both mdb files in the same verion of access at the same time, then dragging and dropping tables from one to the other.

I have Access 2013 and I've used this before.

I don't really get why you are updating the old version to be in a new version but yet you are copying tables from a different new version to the old one?  Surely, update the old version to the new version THEN copy tables.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to update our customers software using code so they can just run an update installer. I can do that on my machine though yes.

Comment: Hey @Jeff.  What about my third paragraph?

Comment: I have tried to edit it to be more clear. I am only adding a new table to the database. Both versions will be .mdb databases(access 2003) I only need to import one table. When I say version I was referring to our Company version of our code, not the version of Access.

Comment: I won't be able to help you, but you might find some useful code here in this rather nifty framework for access https://www.arrow-of-time.com/AXF.aspx